# Bash syntax highlighting of subshells

Tags: bash, syntax-highlighting, subshell

Considering the large amount of questions which turn out to be related to subshells in Bash ("Why doesn't my variable increment in this [piped `while read` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_-r.3B_do_.28.28count.2B-.2B-.29.29.3B_done)?"), I just thought it would be very nice to refer to some editor or service where code which will be executed in subshells is formatted differently from the code executed in the parent shell. It might be useful as an educational device (see the difference between `code | code` and `code < <(code)` instantly). Does this exist?

Bonus points if anyone implements it for jEdit or VIm.

Obviously it doesn't have to be perfect (no syntax highlighting is, in my experience), but I suspect things like `(foo=bar; echo $foo;)` and `command | while read ...` shouldn't be too difficult for a start.

Comment: I'm sure you could add it to `vim`'s code highlighting.

Comment: @Kevin: The question is rather whether it *already* exists, in *any* form. It could of course be added to any editor which supports a Turing-complete highlighting system.

Comment: In the case of the piped while loop, POSIX doesn't specify which part of the pipe executes in the parent, so as a teaching tool, this highlighting, if it existed, would teach people to write non-portable shell scripts :(

Comment: @JamesYoungman: Another reason to make it Bash-specific :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this exists. It would be useful, but hard to implement by standard means of syntax parsing used in editors. From the parsing point of view, there are many keywords and special symbols that would have to be analysed to determine a block of code that belongs to a subshell.

But I'd be happy to see I'm wrong and someone has put the effort needed to create such configurations.

Answer (score 1):

My Vim already does this.

It actually bothers me, because it causes comments inside of the subshells not to get the proper highlight applied.

[image]

This is Vim 7.3 patch 874 compiled from source.

Comment: Sometimes I set the filetype to `zsh` when I'm working within a subshell. That corrects the syntax highlighting.

Comment: OMG that is perfect. Thanks!! I have to have this entire huge block (with many comments) inside the subshell so that I can do the `set -x; set -e` on that section. And to capture all of that output including stderr to a log.

Comment: I don't see *any* formatting in the subshell, which doesn't seem very useful. Or is it just missing from the screenshot?

Comment: the variable set and `trap` keyword are highlighted there. it just failed to highlight comments. the zsh file type works though. Now, as far as differentiating the sub shell from the main shell, (which after all is what you wanted I guess), well....... use some comments?